# Dataframe adding rows no returning correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this.

```
| |  website   |  instance|     timestamp|  length|
|-|---------    |----------|--------------|--------|
|0|    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09|    -641|
|1|    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09|      24|
|2|    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09|     -24|
|3|    facebook |        60|  1.640108e+09|      24|
|4|    Facebook |        60|  1.650108e+09|      24|
|5|    Facebook |        40|  1.650108e+09|      34|
```

Where I want to every "group" have the same number of data. In this case, this is the result that I want:

```
|   | website   |  instance|     timestamp|  length|
| - | --------    |----------|--------------|--------|
| 0 |    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09|    -641|
| 1 |    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09|      24|
| 2 |    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09|     -24|
| 3 |    facebook |        60|  1.640108e+09|      24|
| 4 |    Facebook |        60|  1.650108e+09|      24|
| 5 |    Facebook |        60|  1.650108e+09|      24|
| 5 |    Facebook |        40|  1.650108e+09|      124|
| 5 |    Facebook |        40|  1.650108e+09|      124|
| 5 |    Facebook |        40|  1.650108e+09|      124|
```

For this first of all, I group the data for website and instance. And I call a function to get the maximum of rows of all the groups, and add the data in the other groups.

```
df_group = df.groupby(['website', 'instance'])
 
result =  df_group.apply(lambda x: add_package(x, ((df_group['length'].count()).max())))
```

this is the function:

```
def add_package(x: pd.DataFrame, max_value: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    website = x['website'].iloc[0]
    instance = x['instance'].iloc[0]
    new_package = pd.DataFrame({'website': website, 'instance': instance, 'timestamp': 1, 'length': 1460}, index=[0])
    package_to_add = max_value - x['length'].count()
    x = x.append([new_package]*package_to_add, ignore_index=True)
    return x
```

The problem is that this function at the end is returning me, something like this:

```
| website.  | instance | | website     | instance | timestamp     | length |
| -------   | -------- |-| --------    | -------- | ------------- | ------ |
| bing      |   55     |0|    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09 |   -641 |
|           |          |1|    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09 |     24 |
|           |          |2|    bing     |        55|  1.620108e+09 |    -24 |
| facebook  | 60       |3|    facebook |        60|  1.640108e+09 |     24 |
|           |          |4|    Facebook |        60|  1.650108e+09 |     24 |
|           |          |5|    Facebook |        60|  1.           |     24 |
| facebook  | 60       |3|    facebook |        40|  1.640108e+09 |     124 |
|           |          |4|    Facebook |        40|  1.650108e+09 |     124 |
|           |          |5|    Facebook |        40|  1.           |     124 |
```

And the result that I want the dataframe original, but with the new rows added. How I can do it? this is a reduced example, the original contains more data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.explode()` to even-out the number of rows:

```py
g = df.groupby(["website", "instance"])
max_len = g.size().max()
x = g.agg(lambda x: list(x) + [x.iloc[-1] for _ in range(max_len - len(x))])

df_out = x.explode("timestamp")
df_out["length"] = x["length"].explode()
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
    website  instance     timestamp length
0  Facebook        60  1640108000.0     24
1  Facebook        60  1650108000.0     24
2  Facebook        60  1650108000.0     24
3      bing        55  1620108000.0   -641
4      bing        55  1620108000.0     24
5      bing        55  1620108000.0    -24
```

---

EDIT: If you have this dataframe:

```
    website  instance     timestamp  length
0      bing        55  1.620108e+09    -641
1      bing        55  1.620108e+09      24
2      bing        55  1.620108e+09     -24
3  facebook        60  1.640108e+09      24
4  Facebook        60  1.650108e+09      24
5  Facebook        40  1.650108e+09      34
```

Then:

```
df["website"] = df["website"].str.lower()

g = df.groupby(["website", "instance"])
max_len = g.size().max()
x = g.agg(lambda x: list(x) + [x.iloc[-1] for _ in range(max_len - len(x))])

df_out = x.explode("timestamp")
df_out["length"] = x["length"].explode()
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
    website  instance     timestamp length
0      bing        55  1620108000.0   -641
1      bing        55  1620108000.0     24
2      bing        55  1620108000.0    -24
3  facebook        40  1650108000.0     34
4  facebook        40  1650108000.0     34
5  facebook        40  1650108000.0     34
6  facebook        60  1640108000.0     24
7  facebook        60  1650108000.0     24
8  facebook        60  1650108000.0     24
```

Comment: thanks, but with more data is not working at all

Comment: @dflkaksjf Without seeing real data it's hard to come with some general solution - maybe you need to "clean" the data first (fill NaN values, put the strings in lowercase etc...)